# PHP Email: To, CC

Tags: php, email, carbon-copy

I have a PHP script that automatically send outs an email.  I have it working great, but when I try to add a CC, it doesn't work.  Below is my code for the email to:

```
$email_to = "$theData2"; // Who the email is to 

$headers = "From: ".$email_from; 

$ok = @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

I have tried the following to get CC to work, but I haven't had any luck.

```
$email_cc = "example@info.com"; 
$headers .= "CC: ".$email_cc;
```

and also have tried this:

```
$headers .= "CC: sombodyelse@noplace.com";
```

I can't get it to email to both the: to & cc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Don't use PHPs `mail()` function directly. It is much easier and safer to use a library such as PHPMailer or SwiftMailer.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot your newline.

```
$headers .= "\r\nCc: ".$email_cc;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try ending your header entries with `"\r\n"`:

```
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with "Cc" and not "CC" ? And do not forget the "\n" at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use PHPs `mail()` function directly. Use a wrapper class such as [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) or [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/). They give you far more flexibility and are safer.